# Accessing element within border through Children[] indexing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, children, textblock

I'm trying to access the TextBlock "fastcolor" that is within a border.

The Border lies within a DockPanel named fastcard which i passed as a parameter to another class.

My question is: how do I access the TextBlock named "fastcolor" that is within the border?

This code:

```
(TextBlock)fastcard.Children[0]
```

Gives access to the border, while this code:

```
(TextBlock)fastcard.Children[1]
```

Gives access to the TextBlock named "fastprice"

XAML:

```
<DockPanel Canvas.ZIndex="1" x:Name="fastcard" Background="White" Width="225" Height="300" Visibility="Hidden">
                        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="fastcolor" FontSize="10" Foreground="Black" Width="225" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Visible" />
                        </Border>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="fastprice" Text="Price: " FontSize="15" Foreground="Black" Width="150" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="-290,50,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must traverse the visual tree to get the element. Based on this example ([How to: Find DataTemplate-Generated Elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-find-datatemplate-generated-elements?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#example)), you can either lookup the element by its type or, after some minor modification, by its name. This recursive algorithm allows you to retrieve any element without any knowledge of the exact visual tree composition.

```cs
// The parameter 'obj' is the parent element.
// In your case this is the DockPanel.
private FrameworkElement FindVisualChildByName(DependencyObject obj, string elementName)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (child != null 
          && child is FrameworkElement element
          && element.Name.Equals(elementName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return element;
        }
        else
        {
            FrameworkElement childOfElement = FindVisualChild(element, elementName);
            if (childOfElement != null)
                return childOfChild;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Example**

```cs
var textBlock = FindVisualChildByName(this.fastcard, "fastcolor") as TextBlock;
```